# AS3 How to create a custom list item renderer with image(base64 png string) at runtime

Tags: apache-flex, list, custom-renderer

I'm a newbie to Flex.
I'm trying to create a list with icons. There're a lot of examples but seems all of them are using embedded images.
My problem is how can I create the list with icon from base64 png string at runtime?

Comment: Can I ask why you're using a base64 string and not the actual image itself over say, http?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Base64Image](http://flexlib.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/flexlib/controls/Base64Image.html) from [flexlib](http://code.google.com/p/flexlib/wiki/ComponentList) (first item in that component list) with [this as an example](http://flexlib.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/examples/Base64Image_Sample.swf).